# Can you create a sequence on a column that already exists in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I have a table `linelevelpmts` with a column `seq` (Int4) which is to be used as a sequence.

I know I can delete the column and recreate it as type serial, but can I modify the existing column to be used as a sequence.

```
ALTER TABLE "public"."linelevelpmts" ALTER COLUMN "seq" SET DEFAULT nextval('linelevelpmts_seq_seq'::regclass);
```

This code generates an error: Relation linelevelpmts_seq_seq does not exist.

Comment: "*with a column to be used as a sequence*" does not really make sense. You don't *use* columns like a sequence. You provide their default value from a sequence.

Comment: The table was created programmatically during a data import. I know I can delete the table and recreate it, I just wanted to know if there was another way.

Comment: @kipsoft A sequence is not a column. It is a separate object in a database that produce sequential numbers (for whatever purpose). Sequence can be used as a default value for a column (known as `SERIAL` data type).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> *This code generates an error: Relation linelevelpmts_seq_seq does not exist.*

Well you need to first create the sequence you want to use for the default value:

```
create sequence linelevelpmts_seq_seq;
ALTER TABLE public.linelevelpmts 
    ALTER COLUMN seq SET DEFAULT nextval('linelevelpmts_seq_seq'::regclass);
```

If you want the same effect as if it was created as `serial` you also need to change the "owner" of the sequence:

```
alter sequence linelevelpmts_seq_seq owned by linelevelpmts.seq;
```

**Edit**

Igor's comment is a good one: if you already have values in the column `seq` you should adjust the starting value of the sequence:

```
select setval('linelevelpmts_seq_seq', (select max(seq) from linelevelpmts));
```

Comment: @kipsoft You may additionally need to set created sequence to `max(seq) from linelevelpmts`. Otherwise `nextval('linelevelpmts_seq_seq')` will produce values starting from 1 (duplicates with values already in `linelevelpmts`).

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: thanks, very good point. I added an example on how to adjust the current value of the sequence.

Comment: One can also use `... START WITH <starvalue>` when creating a sequence.

Comment: @vyegorov: yes, but you can't supply a query for the value to be used.