# Column Data Type wont change to serial

Tags: postgresql

I want to change a column data type from integer to a serial

```
ALTER TABLE "TestTable" ALTER COLUMN "ID" TYPE serial ;
```

but it seem can to change for anything except serial !!
i got this error

ERROR:  type "serial" does not exist
********** Error **********

ERROR: type "serial" does not exist
SQL state: 42704

is there any way to solve the problem ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: serial is a pseudo data type. Check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307835/how-to-convert-primary-key-from-integer-to-serial

Comment: that dint solve anything of what i am trying to do!!

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25972630/330315 or this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/78732/1822